# Does MLE really care about PDF?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood

I am wondering, whether MLE really cares whether it operates on proper distributions. Lets take a look at the following situation:

likelihood:
$$L(\theta \mid x) = \prod_{n}^{N}{f(x_n \mid \theta)}$$
or log-likelihood:
$$L(\theta \mid x) = \sum_{n}^{N}{ \log\bigl( f(x_n \mid \theta) \bigr)}$$

Now, lets say that the $f(x \mid\theta)$ is not proper probability distribution, e.g.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x \mid \theta)}dx \neq1$$

then I can normalize it as follows:

$$f_{ \text{norm}}(x, \mid \theta) = \frac{f(x, \mid \theta)}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x \mid \theta)}dx}$$

where the $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(x \mid \theta)}dx = K = \text{const}$. Then, when I maximize the MLE:

$$\underset{\theta}{\operatorname{argmax}}\, L(x,\theta)$$

The $K$ is irrelevant in maximization, such that maximizing with or without $K$ still gives the same $\theta$.

---

Does the above prove the MLE doesnt care whether it operates on proper distribution function, as long as $0\leq f(x,\theta)$ ?

Which implies that any **non-negative measure of distance**, can be used for MLE (that is, the $f(x,\theta)$ can be **skewed** or **stretched** or with **multiple modes**, etc), is that correct ?

---

EDIT:

From the comments I have realized one thing, the $f(x \mid \theta) \leq M$, where $M$ is finite. This refers to the question, where I assume that I take a proper pdf and **stretch** it (not multiply), **add modes** or **skew** it. This is not as specific as it may seem, because what happens is that I take a Normal distribution, and make it's mean $\mu$ as a function of another variable $\mu(z)$ and use MLE over the variable $z$.

The "EDIT" does not extend the problem, only explains and justifies the assumption.

Comment: There are lots of improper distributions that can't be normalized as you've suggested because the integral of the density doesn't converge.  You can easily run into situations where the maximum likelihood is unbounded.  It's also possible to have infinitely many maximum likelihood estimates that you'd need to pick from.

Comment: My non-expert opinion would be: (1) If $f$ is not a pdf or pmf, then multiplying them together as $\Pi f(x_n)$ is problematic to begin with, because the multiplication presumes they are independent samples.  (2) But if you are not troubled by the multiplication, or better yet, if $N=1$ and no multiplication is involved, then you're just maximizing something and sure, it doesn't have to be a pdf / pmf, as long as you can justify to yourself that maximizing is the right thing to do to estimate $\theta$.  (3) Now I will eagerly wait to see what the actual experts have to say. :)

Comment: I think you are asking: Is maximizing $h(\theta)$ the same as maximizing $ch(\theta) + b$ for some given constants $b,c$ with $c>0$?  Yes.

Comment: @Michael Well, if you boil it down so much then yeah. But I am curious whether it makes sence in the terms of MLE.

Comment: @antkam I am not sure how the multiplication of improper pdf(s) prevents the samples from being independent ? Can you please clarify ?

Comment: @MartinG : I do not know how your question is different from the "boiled down" one in my first comment, with the additional statement "assume the $h(\theta)$ function is useful for an MLE problem." (That additional statement does not really change the question.)

Comment: @Michael If you compare your transformation in the comment and the transformation explained in the text, you will find out that yours is linear, while I assume non-linear transformation. Therefore "boil down" means, that you have assumed the simplest possible case, which may not hold in general. If you think there is something unclear, you need to point it by asking the right question or give suggestions, instead of pushing your opinion through.

Comment: You are comparing maximizing $\log[f(\theta)]$ to maximizing $\log[f(\theta)/k]$ for some fixed constant $k>0$. Indeed there is a linear relation between the two because $$\log[f(\theta)/k] = \log[f(\theta)] - \log[k]$$  Nevertheless it also holds that for any strictly increasing function $g(x)$, maximizing $f(\theta)$ is the same as maximizing $g(f(\theta))$.  This fact is already implicit in the log transformation described at the start of your post (the $\log()$ function is strictly increasing).